# how to remove declaration after an include

Tags: c

I am migrating a project to a new toolchain and there are function name collisions, coming from function which are in both my code and the includes from the new toolchain.  My code must now compile in the old and the new toolchain, so I can't just hack.

for example within the same includes, the new toolchain has a qsort function already implemented (and part of the standard libs... so I can't just ignore it), but I have my own and wish to retain the one I have control over.

Is there a way to remove declarations (un-declare?) symbols in order to use those which are local to my project instead?

I have searched for a while and have not found any strategies to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C standard does not provide any way to remove declarations, and I have not heard of any extensions that do. Your options include:

- Rename the identifiers in your source code that conflict with standard library identifiers. This is what you **should** do.
- Use `#define` and `#undef` before and after including any standard header file to change the conflicting names to something else. An example is below. This violates standard C rules about reserved identifiers and may cause problems, depending on the C implementation you use.
- Use `#define` to change your identifier names. This also technically violates standard C rules but is unlikely to cause problems with C implementations. This would need to be done in every source file that uses the identifier. Examples are below. The idea here is the cause every instance where you use your own `qsort` identifier (or other identifier that conflicts) to be replaced in the preprocessor by another identifier that does not conflict.
- You can modify the header files in your C implementation. This is almost always a bad idea. I mention it only to include all possibilities. (Another possibility I do not include, because it is an even worse idea, is that you can modify the source code of the C implementation to provide a new extension that removes declarations.)

Here is an example of the second item:

```
#define qsort StandardLibraryQsortRenamedDueToConflict
#include <stdlib.h>
#undef qsort
```

Here is an example of the third item:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#define qsort MyQsort
#include "MyHeader.h"
```

If you include standard header files after one of your own header files, and you cannot reorder them, you must use `#undef` to avoid interfering with the standard header file:

```
#define qsort MyQsort
#include "MyHeader0.h"
#undef qsort
#include <stdlib.h>
#define qsort MyQsort
#include "MyHeader1.h"
```

If no standard header files are included after any of your troublesome header files in any source file, then, instead of inserting the above in every source file, you can simply place each `#define` in its corresponding header file. So `MyHeader.h` might look like:

```
… // Various code.
#define qsort MyQsort
void qsort(parameter…)
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally, the toolchain *shouldn't* matter. The compiler should never automatically include anything for you, so what gets included is up to you.  Where this falls apart is in dependencies: You `#include x.h`, and the new toolchain provides an `x.h` that also includes `y.h` where the old one did not.

One solution is to fix your code: you really shouldn't be making functions named something like `qsort` that would conflict with a standard library function.  Is there anything stopping you from renaming it to `my_qsort`?  The other reason this is a "good idea", is because if there are any differences between your implementation and the stdlib's, you could have problems: minor problems being developer confusion over different behavior; major problems being linking against the *wrong* version when using prototypes with different signatures (i.e. crash!)

Another solution is to use `#ifdef`s around headers that are only needed on one toolchain, but this might not work in the `x.h` including `y.h` scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a common problem and unfortunately it relies on the author of the library code to use unique names. The win32 windows API headers are notoriously bad in this area.

There is no way to 'undeclare' symbols but If you are using c++ then you can always put your code in a namespace to avoid the clash.

Another option of course is to simply rename your function or add it to a DLL/SO and expose a visible function with a different name.

Comment: Sorry, i only just started using stack overflow, couldn't see where the language was specified.

Comment: No problem. The tags are easy to miss at first.