# error: conflicting types for in "function" in c

Tags: c, header, conditional-statements, include, conflict

```
In file included from 
netscaler/libccauth/ccauth/platform.h:28,
from netscaler/libccauth/ccauth.h:14,
from sys/ccauth/Just_Check.h:1,
from sys/nwaas/ns_nws.c:79:

include/unistd.h:357: error: conflicting types for 'pause'
sys/sys/systm.h:383: error: previous declaration of 'pause' was 
here
```

I am getting these kind of conflict error, How should I approach to resolve such conflict ?

```
int   pause(void);   — defined in include/unistd.h

int   pause(const char *wmesg, int timo); — defined in 
sys/sys/systm.h
```

Comment: If `unistd.h` and `systm.h` has different declarations for `pause`, you can't include both in the same project. Select which type you want and only include that header file.

Comment: Don't include both headers in the compilation of any one source file.  Decide which version of `pause()` you are going to use — I'd recommend the POSIX standard one defined in `<unistd.h>` — and don't use the other anywhere in your code.

Comment: System.h is being used since past. I am new to project, I am not sure where else this library is being used. can I resolve this by some conditionals ?

Comment: @Gandharvakumar No, you can't. Perhaps read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156519/how-to-remove-declaration-after-an-include

Comment: @Gandharvakumar You need to study the code in details to figure out why both files are include. Start by removing one of them and compile. Then do the opposite. From the compilation messages you may learn what is used from these files.

Comment: You mention 'System.h' in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70210178/error-conflicting-types-for-in-function-in-c#comment124113208_70210178) and `sys/sys/systm.h` in the question.  Is either spelling correct?  Which one?

Comment: spelling error.